# How to bind a Spring User with a domain object?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Trying to move the example from Spring documentation one step further, I would like to bind instances of a model "Bank Account" to instances of in-memory users. The intention is that two different users should see only their own account balance after logging in.

The documentation is here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

The user is built using the `UserDetailsService`

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user =
         User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();

         // (*) <-- I guess here I would somehow
         //         bind an instance of `savingsAccount`.

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```

For testing purposes, I'd like to bind an object of a simple account model class to such a user instance. The following shows what this class would look like in a persistence-oriented approach. I don't know how to define it as an in-memory only type.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SavingsAccount {

    @Id
    private int id;

    // In cents.
    private long savings;
}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use your own class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
@ToString
public class User implements UserDetails {
  //Have your bankaccount instance mapping here
}
```

Comment: Thanks I shall try this.